# Problem with changing the radius of corners in MaterialCardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, material-components-android, material-components

I’m trying to disable the bottom corner rounding of `MaterialCardView`, but after applying it, all corners lose their rounding.

```kotlin
        mainCard.shapeAppearanceModel = mainCard.shapeAppearanceModel.toBuilder()
            .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 0f)
            .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 0f)
            .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, resources.getDimension(R.dimen.cornerSize))
            .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, resources.getDimension(R.dimen.cornerSize))
            .build()
```

My layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/mainCard"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: It should work. Which version are you using and what is `R.dimen.cornerSize` ?

Comment: I tested it on `1.2.0`, but I also tried it on `1.3.0-alpha02`. The `cornerSize` is 12dp, but it doesn't matter either, because if I set all corners to this value in the runtime, all rounding works fine.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue but try to use:         `mainCard.shapeAppearanceModel = mainCard.shapeAppearanceModel.toBuilder()
            .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 0f)
            .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 0f).build()`

Comment: Doesn't work for me... I've created an [example](https://gist.github.com/RuslanDemyanov/d31c9f08758d43bf2fb414f830170e36) of how I test it.

Comment: Your issue is not the cardView. Remove the `android:background="@android:color/white"` in `ConstraintLayout` and use `app:cardBackgroundColor` in the `CardView` just to check.

Comment: It solved the problem, but is it possible to change the color of internal content with saving the shape of corner rounding?

Comment: Try something like:`app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false" app:cardUseCompatPadding="false" app:contentPadding="4dp"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/mainCard"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false" 
    app:contentPadding="4dp"
    ..>
```